# Can't run mongodb from wsl ubuntu

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've got problem with running mongodb on wsl ubuntu.

During using powershell everything works fine. I type `node db.js` and its working. After switching terminal to ubuntu and run the same command i get an error: `"MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017".`

Any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: I guess that ubuntu uses different ip than windows

Answer (score 0):

Try to check mongod service status via cli

use `service mongod status` to check

If it's not active then try to activate

use this `sudo service mongod start`

If mongod service is not found then try to install the mongodb